# Scroll and border CSS issues

Tags: html, css

I am almost done w/ my menu here. However I have two issues.

1. I can't add a 1px solid border #fff on the last item of the list.
2. I need to remove the vertical scrollbar on the left.

Here's my CSS:

```
#nav li ul {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0px;
}

#nav li a {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 25px;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 2;
  text-decoration: none
}

#nav li a:hover {
  color: #c0392b;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}



#nav ul li { 
    background-color: #e74c3c; 
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    list-style: disc;
}

#nav li:first-child { 
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}

#nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}



#nav .fa { margin: 0px 17px 0px 0px; }

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#logo{
color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-style: normal;
}

.sidebar-icon {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  color: #fff;
}

.disp {
  opacity: 1!important;
  height:auto!important;
   transition: height 100ms ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 300ms;
}

#nav li span:first-child {
  margin-left: 32px;
}
```

asdasdasdasdasdasdasdassa

Answer (score 1):

*Well, first remove this:*

```
#nav li:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

*for add border to all `li` even last one:*

```
#nav li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

*for removing `scroll` do this:*

**JS:**

```
$('body, html').toggleClass('OverflowHidden');
```

**CSS:**

```
.OverflowHidden {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

*and for removing double border use this:*

```
#nav li ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none!important;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pjb7jzjk/41/)**

Comment: on a side note I don't think it would be desirable to have overflow hidden by default on the html/body, perhaps op can add it as a toggle class when the menu is visible

Comment: for the border its doubling the border of the last child submenu of the dropdown. See screenshot here: http://prnt.sc/as6ibs

Comment: 2. As a follow up to your side note. how can I add that toggle class then? can you show me the jQuery?

Comment: @KimberlyWright I don't see anything in my fiddle.. what's your browser?

Comment: @KimberlyWright yes, I'll update my answer. thanks to David Nguyen for this tip.

Comment: I am using chrome. It has double border.

Comment: I'm using `chrome` too, but i don't see something like this, ok let me find out why. / about `jquery` toggle, if menu is open or close, on both I see scroll, tell me when you want to hide scroll when not? @KimberlyWright

Comment: Yes hide scroll when not. Pl;ease check the dobule border too.

Comment: I don't want to sound pedantic, but a class called `overflowHidden` that sets `overflow: auto`?

Comment: just for fun ;) @Luca I will change it to `.blahBlahblah`